# MySQL: "Patch" existing data on a table from values in another table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mariadb

I have two tables, identical in structure. First one is populated with records obtained from another system that potentially needs corrections (could be one or many columns). Second table is corrections that I want to apply to the first table.

For example, I could have the following rows on table1:

```
order_number | name         | email        | tracking_no
101            null           foo@bar.com    3456789
102            An Example     ex@ample.com   1010101
```

...and the corrections I want to apply to these rows on table2:

```
order_number | name         | email        | tracking_no
101            Name Surname   null           null
102            null           null           45778901
```

Essentially: Add missing `name` to `order_number` 101 and correct the wrong `tracking_no` for `order_number` 102.

The logic of what I am trying to do is: "Patch" values in table1 with the corrections contained for the same `order_number` in table2, giving precedence over to values in table2 and not overwriting existing values in table1 if the corresponding value in table2 is a null.

For the case where a value is null in table1 and we have a non-null correction in table2, `COALESCE` seems to be the right way to go but I can't figure out how to overwrite an already existing value with the corresponding "fix" from table2.

Is there a mechanism in MySQL/MariaDB that would allow me to do this as the alternative is a very messy "pull two records from two tables, compare values and build up the new correct record and insert it back into table1".

As pointed out in comments, here is a reproducible set of test data along with table structures:

```
USE so_demo;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS so_demo.table1;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS so_demo.table2;

CREATE TABLE so_demo.table1 (
  order_number int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  email varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  tracking_no varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (order_number),
  UNIQUE INDEX UK_table1_order_number (order_number)
)
ENGINE = INNODB,
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE so_demo.table2 (
  order_number int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  email varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  tracking_no varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (order_number),
  UNIQUE INDEX UK_table2_order_number (order_number)
)
ENGINE = INNODB,
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;

INSERT INTO so_demo.table1 VALUES (101, NULL, "foo@bar.com", 3456789);
INSERT INTO so_demo.table1 VALUES (102, "An Example", "ex@ample.com", 1010101);

INSERT INTO so_demo.table2 VALUES (101, "Name Surname", NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO so_demo.table2 VALUES (102, NULL, NULL, 45778901);
```

Comment: Do you have indexes on your table 1

Comment: @P.Salmon Yes, order_number is a unique index.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry That is fair, added structure and test data on the question

Comment: Can you edit to show what the desired result would actually look like after the UPDATE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you are looking for is merge and in mysql an insert on duplicate key

```
drop table if exists t,t1;

create table t(order_number int primary key, name  varchar(20)       , email  varchar(20), tracking_no int);
insert into t values
(101       ,     null       ,     'foo@bar.com'  ,  3456789),
(102       ,     'An Example',     'ex@ample.com' ,  1010101);

create table t1(order_number int, name  varchar(20), email  varchar(20), tracking_no int);
insert into t1 values
(101       ,     'Name Surname', null   ,        null),
(102       ,     null          , null   ,        '45778901');


insert into t
select * from t1
on duplicate key update
    t.name = case when t1.name is not null then t1.name else t.name end,
    t.email = case when t1.email is not null then t1.email else t.email end,
    t.tracking_no = case when t1.tracking_no is not null then t1.tracking_no else t.tracking_no end
;

select * from t;

+--------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
| order_number | name         | email        | tracking_no |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
|          101 | Name Surname | foo@bar.com  |     3456789 |
|          102 | An Example   | ex@ample.com |    45778901 |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: t.name=Coalesce(t1.name, t.name) :)

Comment: This is what I was trying to achieve, thank you @P.Salmon! One further query: I don't mind just duplicating the case statements but the actual table I am dealing with has about 50 colums. Is there a shorthand for apply the same case statement to all columns? Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid not - though as has been pointed out coalesce is less verbose.